# Crystal Reports Check If String Contains Any Numerical Value

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I'm using Crystal Reports and in 1 of my formulas, I'd like to check if a string contains any numerical value or not. Examples are shown below...

```
"Chris(12)" Returns True
"123"       Returns True
"Pot"       Returns False
"John0"     Returns True
```

I've already achieved what I want using the INSTR() function. I did it like this...

```
if INSTR(string,"0") <> 0 or INSTR(string,"1") <> 0 or INSTR(string,"2") <> 0 ... then
   True
else
   False
```

I'd just like to know if there's any shorter or more efficient code. Thank you very much.

Comment: check this post http://scn.sap.com/thread/1680390, you have to change a bit the code, but I think that's the solution

Comment: Thanks for this :) But I don't think the solution provided is enough for me to say "hey, this is more efficient". But thank you very much for this. I created something like this before I had my solution above. I just didn't like it.

Comment: I would have told you to use the regular expressions but crystal doesn't seem to support it :(

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom function named `ContainsNumber`:

```
Function (Stringvar text)

  Local Booleanvar found := False;
  Local Numbervar i;

  For i := 1 To Len(text) Do (

    If IsNumeric(Mid(text, i, 1)) Then (
      found := True;
      Exit For
    )

  );

  found;
```

Use in formula field:

```
// FALSE
ContainsNumber ("ABC")

// TRUE
ContainsNumber ("ABC123")
```