# A Statement is expected here

Tags: crystal-reports

I have 2 table rows which is TABLE.ROW1 & TABLE.ROW2 and both contain numbers
on my database table row1 & row2 are varchars type.

```
IF (INSTR({TABLE.ROW1})) > (INSTR({TABLE.ROW2})) 
OR (INSTR({TABLE.ROW1})) = (INSTR(TABLE.ROW2})) THEN (INSTR({TABLE.ROW1}))
ELSEIF (INSTR({TABLE.ROW1})) < (INSTR(TABLE.ROW2)) THEN "FAIL"
```

The problem is, crystal report always show this error message; "A statement is expected here".
this problem was troublesome, i think it came from conversion thing. could somebody help?

reference link:
[i have try using INSTR but still no result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087675/crystal-reports-check-if-string-contains-any-numerical-value)
Adding samples results:

[my objective is to create table like this on the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxott.jpg)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the two rows? what is your exact requirement?

Comment: i have add sample result image for you.. thank you for your attention

Comment: `InStr()` function requires at least two parameters.

Comment: Hi Arvo, sorry i didnt understand much about crystal report, what did you mean about 2 parameters?

Comment: Is there any specific reason using `INSTR` you can directly compare the results..

Comment: for convert the value to number as i saw on previous links that i attached to my question. before that i used ISNUMBER for each table row but seems to be the same result

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer, i didn't know this is the correct one or not, but this was show correctly at my crystal report. i create separate formula to convert the value to number and other formula to run the conversion results

@1st formula:

`IF isnumeric({Table.Row1}) = true then tonumber({Table.Row1}) else 0`

@2nd formula:

`IF isnumeric({Table.Row2}) = true then tonumber({Table.Row2}) else 0`

then at the final formula:

`IF {@1st} > {@2nd} OR {@1st} = {@2nd} THEN {Table.Row1}
ELSE IF {@1st} < {@2nd} THEN "FAIL"`